# Data disappears after populating the data

Tags: datatables

I have this DataTable:

```
<table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-advance table-hover" id="tabela_1">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>ID</th>
            <th>Name</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>

    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

I want to fill the table with data, using AJAX call. I have the following AJAX code:

```
function SearchResult(){

      $.ajax({
          url: 'php/search.php,
          type: 'get',
          data: $("#form_search").serialize(),
          dataType: 'json',
          success: function (data) {
            if (data.success) {
                $("#tabela_1 > tbody").html("");
                $.each(data, function (index, record) {
                  if ($.isNumeric(index)) { 
                    var row = $("<tr />");
                    $("<td />").text(record.ID).appendTo(row);
                    $("<td />").text(record.name).appendTo(row);
                    row.appendTo('#tabela_1');
                  }
                });
            }
          }
        });
    }
```

At this point I get the table filled (after calling the `SearchResult()` function).

But, when I press the table column to sort that column, all the data disappear. The same happens when I use the table search box.
I've tried to use the `fnDraw()` and `fnUpdate()` but with no effect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not recommended to use `<tr>`/`<td>` nodes to add data to the table, use appropriate DataTables API methods instead, for example [`row.add()`](http://datatables.net/reference/api/row.add%28%29).

**JavaScript:**

```
success: function (data) {
   var table = $("#tabela_1").DataTable();

   if (data.success){
      table.clear();
      $.each(data, function (index, record){
         if ($.isNumeric(index)) {
            table.row.add([record.ID, record.name]);
         }
      });

      table.draw();
   }
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-advance table-hover" id="tabela_1">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>ID</th>
            <th>Name</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
</table>
```